# Facebook Graph API get comments from Comments Plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all comments from Facebook Comments Plugin running in my application.

Here's a step by step of what i have done

1. https://graph.facebook.com/{myUrl}

   ```
   {
      "share": {
         "comment_count": 43,
         "share_count": 1695
      },
      "og_object": {
         "id": {myObjectID},
         "description": {myDescription},
         "title": {myTitle},
         "type": "website",
         "updated_time": "2018-05-28T21:50:37+0000"
      },
      "id": {myUrl}
   }
   ```
2. https://graph.facebook.com/{myObjectID}/comments?access_token={pageToken}

   ```
   {
      "data": [    ],
      "paging": {
         "cursors": {
            "before": {beforePointer},
            "after": {afterPointer}
         },
         "next": {nextUrl}
      }
   }
   ```

So despite `comment_count` = 43, data field is empty.
It's also weird that a `{nextUrl}` is given although not showing any results.

Haven't found nothing about this in the recent update due to GDPR.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can’t find anything mentioned either; but seeing how they disabled/limited access to user details on comments in other places (pages, groups), I would not surprise me if this was in the same spirit. With a page or a group there is a way to prove you have admin access, but for external URLs - not really.

Answer (score 0):

The graph API has changed recently due to privacy and GDPR concerns.

To get all comments for a page or user first you need to make a call to get all your posts and then make a call for each post to get comments.

Please view the following example end to get all the posts and then post_ids (the call is similar for user posts).

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{pageId}/posts?access_token={accessToken}
```

post_id looks something like this - 5704324444475_570454233326 and is in the id field of each returned post.

Then call the get comments endpoint from the graph API using the ID(s) returned by the first endpoint.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{post_id}/comments?access_token={accessToken}&summary=true
```

You'll need to make a separate call for each posts to get that post's comments.